Fetch API throws "TypeError: Failed to fetch" while CORS setup done - case with Express + routing-controllers + helmet
I got the unclear error that has been trown by fetch API:
TypeError: Failed to fetch

Basically it occurs when something wrong with COSR settings, but in my case:

I am using the cors package. With routing-controllers package, the setup will be as below:

import Express, { type Express as ExpressApplication } from "express";
import createExpressApplication from "express";
import { useExpressServer as supportClassSyntax } from "routing-controllers";

const expressApplication: ExpressApplication = createExpressApplication();

// ...


supportClassSyntax(
  expressApplication,
  {

    cors: __IS_LOCAL_DEVELOPMENT_BUILDING_MODE__ ?
        {
          credentials: true,
          origin: [ "https://localhost:3002", "https://localhost:443" ]
        } :
        false,

      controllers: [
        // ...
      ],

  }
);


Using the helmet package with default settings.

I have checked that the request is begin processed at backend:
import type User from "@Entities/AccessControl/User";
import AccessControlGateway from "@Gateways/AccessControl/AccessControlGateway";
import type SessionCustomFields from "@FrontServer/AccessControl/SessionCustomFields";
import Express from "express";
import { Session as ExpressSession } from "express-session";
import {
  Controller,
  Body as RequestBody,
  Res as HTTP_Response,
  Session
} from "routing-controllers";


@Controller()
class AccessControlController {

  protected async signIn(
    @RequestBody({ required: true }) requestData: AccessControlGateway.SigningIn.RequestData,
    @HTTP_Response() response: Express.Response,
    @Session() session: ExpressSession & SessionCustomFields
  ): Promise<Express.Response> {

    let targetUser: User | null = /* ... */;

    response.status(200).end();

    console.log("OK!");
    console.log(session.currentAuthenticatedUser);

    return response;

  }

}

Here is the output:

But what is strange is the morgan logger has not log the response code on failed POST-request:

Here is the output of response.getHeaders():
[Object: null prototype] {
  'content-security-policy': "frame-src *.google.com/;default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests",
  'cross-origin-opener-policy': 'same-origin',
  'cross-origin-resource-policy': 'same-origin',
  'origin-agent-cluster': '?1',
  'referrer-policy': 'no-referrer',
  'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains',
  'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
  'x-dns-prefetch-control': 'off',
  'x-download-options': 'noopen',
  'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
  'x-permitted-cross-domain-policies': 'none',
  'x-xss-protection': '0',
  vary: 'Origin',
  'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
  'set-cookie': [
    'connect.sid=s%3AF7igEewHZSI_ku1iijFQsyjyD9MxvTxo.09FDwuC08Mr1rgLlxTO8BcsjxD8GFua6wIrbafn9Y2g; Path=/; HttpOnly'
  ]
}

If to check the "Network" tab of browser console, it will be the request with "cancelled" status:


The content of "Preview" and "Response" tabs is empty:

Currently the server is listening for 443 port and I am submitting the requests from 443.
In the future, the port 3002 must be supported for "Browsersync" usage.
What else coudl be wrong?

Do you see an error in your console when making the POST /api/sign_in request? If so, what is that error?

@EvanHahn, Thank you for the comment. The error in browser console is the unclear Fetch API's error "TypeError: Failed to fetch".

I don't know what's causing it but you could temporarily remove Helmet to see if that's the source of your issue. It's possible that Helmet's default Content Security Policy is preventing these requests.
